# Relationship between concentration of bitcoin wealth and foreign exchange value?

Tags: economic-theory, money-supply, market

Is there a **relationship** between the **equality of wealth of bitcoin** holders, and it's **foreign exchange value**?

E.g. if there is a large transfer of bitcoin to a single owner, should this influence its value as a currency?

Comment: Are you talking about a change in supply/demand or a change in total number of units? If you take into consideration how such an acquisition comes to pass,  I think your question might answer itself. Or I just don't get it. ;]  please clarify?

Comment: You're right, this is ambiguous. i mean if many people transfer their bitcoin to a single holder of bitcoin. Should this decresase demand to buy bitcoin with foreign currencies?